# Keras segmetnation fault during model training on raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, tensorflow, segmentation-fault, keras, raspberry-pi3

I am running a `keras` program on RaspberryPi 3 and get the following Segmentation failure. The program works perfectly on my laptop. The keras was installed and upgraded using `pip`. Tensorflow was installed before it using a .whl meant for Raspberry Pi 3.

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Compiling Labels file...
Labels file compiled!
Loading pretrained model...
Adding additional layers...
Compiling new model file...
Model compiled!
Found 408 images belonging to 5 classes.
Found 87 images belonging to 5 classes.
Training model...
Epoch 1/2

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Sep 30 20:57:40 ...
 kernel:[ 3638.281032] Internal error: Oops: 5 [#2] SMP ARM

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Sep 30 20:57:40 ...
 kernel:[ 3638.385182] Process python (pid: 2199, stack limit = 0xb5382210)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Sep 30 20:57:40 ...
 kernel:[ 3638.391273] Stack: (0xb5383df0 to 0xb5384000)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Sep 30 20:57:40 ...
 kernel:[ 3638.395690] 3de0:                                     b5383e1c b5383e00 80152ac8 8014cc54

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Sep 30 20:57:40 ...
 kernel:[ 3638.403985] 3e00: ace00004 b65d4cd8 b65d4cd8 b6552960 b5383ea4 b5383e20 8012e588 80152a84

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Sep 30 20:57:40 ...
 kernel:[ 3638.412279] 3e20: b5383e6c b5383e30 800894b4 8048d910 4b71ddf2 20000113 b601d500 20000113

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Sep 30 20:57:40 ...
 kernel:[ 3638.420574] 3e40: b601d500 80869e00 80869e00 a7f77000 00000000 00000040 80869e00 b5802800

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Sep 30 20:57:40 ...
 kernel:[ 3638.428869] 3e60: 80869e00 60000113 60000113 801306dc 6a6ff000 ace00000 b5383ea4 b5383fb0

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Sep 30 20:57:40 ...
 kernel:[ 3638.437164] 3e80: ace00000 00000817 6a6ff000 a7df1c00 a7df1c38 00000055 b5383efc b5383ea8

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Sep 30 20:57:40 ...
 kernel:[ 3638.445459] 3ea0: 805b9808 8012d680 805bde5c 8085d3c0 8086060c 8086a080 b5383ee4 b5383ec8

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Sep 30 20:57:40 ...
 kernel:[ 3638.453754] 3ec0: 80028c74 00000000 00000800 00000000 00000009 80865584 00000817 805b94c8

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Sep 30 20:57:40 ...
 kernel:[ 3638.462049] 3ee0: 6a6ff000 b5383fb0 00000000 00000000 b5383fac b5383f00 800091e8 805b94d4

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Sep 30 20:57:40 ...
 kernel:[ 3638.470345] 3f00: 0000000a 60000193 00000000 00000000 01400000 00000000 6b9f71d0 3fcc5a7f

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Sep 30 20:57:40 ...
 kernel:[ 3638.478639] 3f20: b5383f4c b5383f30 8007d258 800d96c8 b601cdc0 8085a4ec 00000000 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Sep 30 20:57:40 ...
 kernel:[ 3638.486933] 3f40: b5383f64 b5383f50 800295e8 8007d1e4 00000000 8085a4ec b5383f8c b5383f68

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Sep 30 20:57:40 ...
 kernel:[ 3638.495227] 3f60: 8007107c 80029550 b5383fb0 73cfc58c 20000010 ffffffff 10c5383d 10c5387d

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Sep 30 20:57:40 ...
 kernel:[ 3638.503522] 3f80: b5383f9c 7498e034 80000010 7498e034 80000010 ffffffff 10c5383d 10c5387d

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Sep 30 20:57:40 ...
 kernel:[ 3638.511817] 3fa0: 00000000 b5383fb0 805b90e4 800091ac 000000e0 6a6ff000 00a96780 6a6fefd0

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Sep 30 20:57:40 ...
 kernel:[ 3638.520111] 3fc0: 000000f8 00000000 66bfed40 00000000 fffff800 00000000 00000000 66bfecfc

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Sep 30 20:57:40 ...
 kernel:[ 3638.528405] 3fe0: 6a6feff0 66bfea80 7498df00 7498e034 80000010 ffffffff 00000000 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Sep 30 20:57:40 ...
 kernel:[ 3638.608041] Code: e8bd4000 e5913004 ee1dcf90 e3130001 (e5903148)
```

Code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import os, sys
import glob
import argparse

from keras import __version__
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Flatten, Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50, preprocess_input

... 
#Code skipped
...

    print ("Model compiled!") #Section causing the error begins here

    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
        rotation_range     = 30,
        width_shift_range  = 0.25,
        height_shift_range = 0.25,
        shear_range        = 0.25,
        zoom_range         = 0.25,
        horizontal_flip    = True
    )

    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
        rotation_range     = 30,
        width_shift_range  = 0.25,
        height_shift_range = 0.25,
        shear_range        = 0.25,
        zoom_range         = 0.25,
        horizontal_flip    = True
    )

    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
      args.train_dir,
      target_size=(IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT),
      batch_size=batch_size,
    )

    validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
      args.val_dir,
      target_size=(IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT),
      batch_size=batch_size,
    )

    print ("Training model...")

    history_tl = model_final.fit_generator(
      train_generator,
      validation_data  = validation_generator,
      class_weight     = 'auto',
      steps_per_epoch  = num_training_steps,
      epochs           = num_epochs,
      validation_steps = num_validation_steps)

    print ("Model training completed!")
```

Would the solution to this problem be to install tensorflow differently? Or is there some easier workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Segmentation Fault is usually associated with some memory error. This is probably because RPI does not have enough memory. You can try

```
sudo raspi-config
```

and allocate more ram to CPU (less ram to GPU). Still, I don't think the extra 64MB or 32MB ram would help.

I would avoid to train any deep learning model on raspberry pi. The Pi is simply not powerful enough. You might be able to train some very simple neural net, but not any decent one. I highly recommend training your model on desktop and copy the pre-trained model to raspberry pi, and load the model and weight, and only run forward computation.

ResNet50 is a pretty large model for raspberry pi. It contains more than 20M parameters. Running a single forward prediction took 8 seconds on my PI 3. It doesn't make too much sense to train it on Pi.